# What's the fastest way to find matches between a list of substrings and a list of strings? Python

Tags: python, list, bioinformatics

I have a long list of strings (3k character-long) and a huge file containing roughly 4 million lists of substrings. What's the fastest way to find if one of the lists contains a substring that matches one of the strings from the other list?

```
for line in infile:

if line.startswith("+"):
    Flag = False

if Flag:
    #this function builds a list of substrings from a single string, it's necessary for the program
    kmers = build_kmers(line[:-1], 19)  

    for g in genes:

            if kmers[k] in genes[g]:
```

Comment: you do `if kmers[k] in genes[g]:` but `k` doesn't exist, so your code won't execute. Then you are for some reason using a flag which when you set to False will never be set to True again. Instead just put a `continue` inside your `if line.startswith("+"):`  and drop the Flag. Having said that, for such big amount of data I'd suggest using `Prefix tries`  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: ty for your help. The real code isn't like this, I just edited it before posting it to make it more clear but apparently I shouldn't have to. I'll try with prefix tries. thank you again

Comment: You can edit the code to make it more clear, but then bear in mind that the answers you will get are according to the code you posted. If you are starting with bioinformatics algorithms I'd suggest you don't try to directly solve problems with 4 millions lists and 3k characters long. Make a small problem that you can solve by hand and know what the result should be, then run the code and see that it does what you expect. Try side cases. Then when you are confident enough try to scale it and see how it performs for larger datasets.